# navigation links not "clickable" on smartphone / tablet

Tags: android, css, mobile, joomla

On a website I'm designing with the Joomlart Mero template, the navigation links arent "clickable" on smartphones / tablets.

For some reason, if you just touch the link like you normally would - nothing happens. It's like you're just touching normal text.

However if you press just a little longer, but not long enough that the context menu pops up - then sometimes the link will work.

I can't figure this out for the life of me...

It's a block-level element with padding, so there shoudn't be an issue that I'm not pressing in the right spot.

The other strange thing is that the nav works perfectly on the theme's demo site ( ja-mero.demo.joomlart.com/index.php/en/ ), however when I remove all custom CSS - I still have issues with the mobile nav links.

http://rwd.itnorthdev.com/

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work here on iPhone

Comment: hmm .. I'm using a Galaxy S4  /  Chrome Browser

Comment: So which of the links are we talking about here? All 73 of them?